# How to add subdrowdownitems to a dropdownitem?

Tags: c#, toolstrip, menustrip

I got a menu item, which when you press different toolstripmenu items show. But I want to add subtoolstripmenu items to a toolstripmenuitem. This is how I thought it would work:

```
ToolStripMenuItem[] items = new ToolStripMenuItem[10];

for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
                items[i] = new ToolStripMenuItem();
                items[i].Name = i;
                items[i].Text = i;
                items[i].Tag =  i;
                items[i].Click += new EventHandler(MenuItemClickHandler);
}
toolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems[2].AddRange(items); //not possible
toolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.AddRange(items); // possible
```

Sadly it only works when I use `toolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.AddRange(items);` but not when I use `toolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems[2].AddRange(items);`. Anyone any idea how to do this?

I dont want it to expand at the red cross, i want the green circle: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFT1v.jpg

Comment: Try casting it: `((ToolStripMenuItem)toolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems[2]).DropDownItems.Add("new menu");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LarsTech's comment is correct.
Replace the last 2 lines with:

```
ToolStripMenuItem subMenu = toolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems[2] as ToolStripMenuItem;
subMenu.DropDownItems.AddRange(items);
```